# How to perform weighted average every 2 rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data looks like this:

```
...
                     A         B      C
2017-09-18 12:00:00  1.000010  18000  100
2017-09-18 17:00:00  1.000029  13500  400
2017-09-19 12:00:00  1.000025  18000  300
2017-09-19 17:00:00  1.000037  13500  300

...
```

At 2 distinct times on the same day measures A, B, and C are taken.

I need to collapse every 2 measures/day into a single row (for example, for the first 2 rows):

- a weighted average of columns A and B

  `((A1 * B1) + (A2 * B2)) / (B1 + B2)`
- an average of column C

  `(C1 + C2) / 2`

My difficulty arises in trying to `df.groupby` these adjacent rows, given they have distinct times and the need to perform a custom operation for columns A B, that is different from C.

My expected output would be:

```
                     A            C
2017-09-18 12:00:00  1.000018143  250
2017-09-19 12:00:00  1.000030143  300
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now my question would be whether there are only two recordings per day always, or is it possible for there to be 1.

Comment: thanks for your patience @coldspeed! yes, only 2 rows per day, consistently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vectorize this with `groupby`, `apply`, and `mean`:

```
def AB_weighted(g):
   return (g['A'] * g['B']).sum() / g['B'].sum()

g = df.groupby(df.index.date)
pd.concat([g.apply(AB_weighted), g['C'].mean()], keys=['A', 'C'], axis=1)

                   A    C
2017-09-18  1.000018  250
2017-09-19  1.000030  300
```

- We need `apply` for the first condition, since the groupby calculation uses multiple columns—"A" and "B".
- For calculating the mean of "C", only "C" is needed, so we can shorten things with `mean()`.

---

Another option is computing the product before the `groupby`, so we can circumvent the call to `apply` (this is a little like @W-B second answer) but with one `sum` call.

```
u = df.assign(D=df['A'] * df['B'])[['D', 'B']].groupby(df.index.date).sum()
u['A'] = u.pop('D') / u.pop('B')

u['C'] = df.groupby(df.index.date)['C'].mean()

u
                   A    C
2017-09-18  1.000018  250
2017-09-19  1.000030  300
```

Answer (score 4):

Check with

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x : pd.Series({'A':sum(x['A']*x['B'])/sum(x['B']),'C':(x['C']).mean()}))
                   A      C
2017-09-18  1.000018  250.0
2017-09-19  1.000030  300.0
```

Or let us do not use apply

```
t1=df.eval('A*B').groupby(df.index.date).sum()/df.groupby(df.index.date).B.sum()
t2=df.groupby(df.index.date).C.mean()

pd.concat([t1,t2],1)
                   0    C
2017-09-18  1.000018  250
2017-09-19  1.000030  300
```